# MSBuildWorkspace OpenSolutionAsync() exits process

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn, projects-and-solutions

In a console application I have been trying to get OpenSolutionAsync to work for a couple of weeks now without success.

Finally I remembered to look at the [roslyn-sdk repository](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk) which contains samples. I locally run the sample called [SolutionExplorer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/tree/master/samples/CSharp/SolutionExplorer) and it works perfectly. I can choose a solution file and it can open the solution.

Given that this sample works, I decided to make my console app similar to it. So I copied the MSBuildService and WorkspaceService (just changing the logging behavior) to my console application. Changed my console app to target v4.6.1 of .NET Framework. Referenced the exact same nuget packages. I made sure to delete the bin folders and also compared the bin folder from the sample with the bin folder generated for my project. They are the same. 
And yet, when I hit the line to OpenSolutionAsync(), my console application just exits the process.

What am I doing wrong?

**More info:**
I copied the project [here](https://github.com/tukaya/CallerId.Scanner) to make it easily reachable for you. Please provide two parameters to run the project e.g:

```
callerid.scanner.exe -p "<path to some solution>" -d "<documentNameToFindInSolution>"
```

It exits the process on line 97 of [WorkspaceService](https://github.com/tukaya/CallerId.Scanner/blob/master/CallerId.Scanner/Lib/Compiler/WorkspaceService.cs)

Comment: What's the exception being thrown and what's it's stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

A few things, sorry it VB but you should get the idea. The important thing is to get the right instance of MSBuild and trap the errors.

```
Property MSBuildInstance As VisualStudioInstance
' Get all instances of MSBuild
Private ReadOnly visualStudioInstances() As VisualStudioInstance = MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances().ToArray()
' Pick the instance of MSBuild you want
MSBuildInstance = visualStudioInstances(???)
MSBuildLocator.RegisterInstance(MSBuildInstance)
Using Workspace As MSBuildWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create()
    AddHandler Workspace.WorkspaceFailed, AddressOf MSBuildWorkspaceFailed
    Dim currentProject As Project = Workspace.OpenProjectAsync(FileName).Result
'  Do something with the project
End Using

' Print message for WorkspaceFailed event to help diagnosing project load failures.
 Private Sub MSBuildWorkspaceFailed(_1 As Object, e1 As WorkspaceDiagnosticEventArgs)
    If MsgBox(e1.Diagnostic.Message, MsgBoxStyle.AbortRetryIgnore, "MSBuild Failed") = MsgBoxResult.Abort Then
        End
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to register a msbuild location with the `MSBuildLocator` class. This will allow the `MSBuildWorkspace` to open solutions and projects. Long story short: it needs to know where msbuild is because it uses it to load projects.

I would place the following code in the constructor of your service

```cs
// Attempt to set the version of MSBuild.
var visualStudioInstances = MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances().ToArray();
var instance = visualStudioInstances.Length == 1
    // If there is only one instance of MSBuild on this machine, set that as the one to use.
    ? visualStudioInstances[0]
    // Handle selecting the version of MSBuild you want to use.
    : SelectVisualStudioInstance(visualStudioInstances);

_logger.WriteLine($"Using MSBuild at '{instance.MSBuildPath}' to load projects.");

// NOTE: Be sure to register an instance with the MSBuildLocator 
//       before calling MSBuildWorkspace.Create()
//       otherwise, MSBuildWorkspace won't MEF compose.
MSBuildLocator.RegisterInstance(instance);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I am already doing this. See [MSBuildService.cs](https://github.com/tukaya/CallerId.Scanner/blob/master/CallerId.Scanner/Lib/Compiler/MSBuildService.cs) . The exact same code works perfectly (opens solution) in the [sample project from roslyn-sdk](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/tree/master/samples/CSharp/SolutionExplorer). But it doesn't work in the console app...

Comment: ah, sorry. pulling down your github repo this issue is that the version of `System.Composition` that you are using is incompatible with the version of `MSBuildWorkspace` you are using.  See [this](https://github.com/tukaya/CallerId.Scanner/pull/1) pull request

Comment: Hi Jonathon, sorry I forgot to answer your comment after fixing the issue. Thanks for your time. The issue was wrong usage of async action. But I upgraded the codeanalysis and msbuildworkspace nuget packages to latest versions. All working now even in .NET Core. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
I was using nuget package [CommandLineParser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline). It has to do with usage of async while triggering the action with CommandLineParser. When I removed async and called OpenSolutionAsync().Result instead, it works.

It seems like CommandLineParser has no support for async implementation. Then OpenSolutionAsync just quits the process when called with await within CommandLineParser's WithParsed method.

This cost me weeks to figure out.. 
Thanks for your answers anyways, @Jonathon Marolf and @Paul Cohen.